# FCM: Notifications disappear

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notificaions. When I get two notifications of my app and click on the first one to show the corresponding post in the app, the second notifcation disappears from the notification area (statusbar).

I checked other apps (e.g. news app) and the behavior is different. When I click the first notification here the second one remains in the status bar.

I searched for options I could specify in my notifications, but I did not find anything appropriate. Maybe I'm missing something. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It would be better if you can share the code on how you send and receive the messages so others can easily help you if there's a problem in your implementation. You can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).